# How do I display database items separated by an ID in Coldfusion?

Tags: mysql, sql, forms, checkbox, coldfusion

I'm trying to display items separated by category. I want it to look like the following:

```
Category 1
----------
option 1
option 2
option 3
```

Each option would have a checkbox next to it. I can't seem to get it to work. This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
<cfquery datasource="applewood" username="username" password="password"
name="getOptions" >
SELECT *
FROM options
</cfquery>

<form action="dbtest.cfm"  id="displayOptions" method="post" name="displayOptions">
<cfif #getOptions.idOpCategories# IS 1>
<cfoutput query="getOptions">
<input type="checkbox" name="#getOptions.idOptions#" id="#getOptions.idOpCategories#">
#getOptions.option# <br />
</cfoutput>
</cfif>
</form>
```

Now even though I used cfif to sort by the idOpCategories number 1, it still lists all of them. When I put a WHERE clause in the query and have idOpCategories = 1 then it works like expected, but do I really have to make different query statements for each number (22 of them)? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the group parameter for cfoutput.   Maybe that's what you're looking for....

Comment: I used group="idOpCategories" which is what I want to sort by but it just eliminated 4 out of 22 categories and is only showing some of each category it shows.

Comment: Inorder to use group in the output you'll want to add `order by idOpCategories` to your query

Comment: I added order by idOpCategories and then put in group="idOpCategories" in the cfoutput and it still gives me random category numbers and eliminates some of them. It doesn't seem to have a pattern.

Comment: `cfif #getOptions.idOpCategories# IS 1` If you only want options for a specific category, why not use a `where` filter in the query instead? That way you are not including a bunch of data that is never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with that logic is, the cfif is looking at idOpCategories of the first query row which it appears idOpCategories EQ 1. The getOptions query doesn't filter so it is returning all rows of data.

You could move your cfif statement like this:

```
<cfoutput query="getOptions">
<cfif idOpCategories eq 1>
<input type="checkbox" name="#getOptions.idOptions#" id="#getOptions.idOpCategories#">
#getOptions.option# <br />
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

But it makes more sense to handle this in the query itself.

Comment: That works, thanks. I'll keep working to see about using the query as well. I still have to display the actual category name now.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try something like this :

```
<cfquery datasource="applewood" name="getOptions" >
     SELECT *
     FROM options
     GROUP BY idOpCategories
</cfquery>

<form action="dbtest.cfm"  id="displayOptions" method="post" name="displayOptions">

<cfoutput query="getOptions" group="idOpCategories">
     <h2>Category #idOpCategories#</h2>
     <cfoutput>
     <input type="checkbox" 
            name="#getOptions.idOptions#" 
            id="#getOptions.idOpCategories#"> #getOptions.option# <br />
     </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>

</form>
```

Add `Order By` on the query and `group` the output

Comment: Thanks but this gives me the same results as above. Some categories are getting eliminated and duplicates are getting skipped from being displayed. I'm still working on it though.

Comment: My mistake the eliminations are due to the missing additional outputs inside the grouped output.  See the revised answer above.